# How much does it cost the airline if an aircraft makes a missed approach?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airline-operations

aircraft go around due to variety of reasons viz. Bad weather (inevitable), unstable approach, ATC errors etc.
knowing the cost implications will help in educating the stakeholders.

Comment: Considering the potential cost of *not* executing a missed approach when warranted, surely the cost of going missed must be smaller. Which stakeholders are you looking to educate, and what education do you feel they need?

Comment: Sometimes the stakeholders are usurped by things beyond the stakeholders control.  I was on a shorter flight from somewhere in Texas to somewhere in Colorado, coming down final in the clouds, when the engines spun up and we went around before we broke out of the clouds. Turns out a truck had pulled up and blocked the ILS signal. I guess pilot notified tower, tower contacted someone else and they got the truck moved away.